# Add a new magic number on Linux

Tags: linux

I am dealing with a new file type that is not recognized by the "file" command, and I need to be able to identify these files even if their extension is changed/removed.

I would like to know if there is a way to add that file type's magic number to the "place" where the "file" command looks for a correspondence. I saw on Google the mention of a magic-number.txt file but I can't find it on my Linux so I guess it's not that.

Does anyone know how/where to add a magic number for a unknown file type on a Linux OS ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer in the file command man page.

> The information identifying these files is read from the compiled
> magic file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc, or the files in the directory
> /usr/share/misc/magic if the compiled file does not exist. In
> addition, if $HOME/.magic.mgc or $HOME/.magic exists, it will be used
> in preference to the system magic files. If /etc/magic exists, it will
> be used together with other magic files.

I should have read it before asking my question, but maybe it can help others too.